# Set Style Value as Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, css, variables, html

I am attempting to create a page where text appears in random locations. For this, I need the left and top distances in a DIV containing text to be created randomly. The following HTML is a basic idea of what I am thinking about.

```
<body>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var leftvar = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
            var topvar = Math.round(Math.random()*1000);
        }
        window.onload = myFunction;
    </script>
    <div style="left:leftvar; top:topvar;">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I put variables in the style CSS of a DIV?

Also, any other ways to have a randomly relocating DIV would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't echo out values like that. You need to do it in the function. Once you have your random numbers, then you need to find the element `document.getElementById` for example, and change the `.style` properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the element with javascript and change it's style properties :

```
<head>
    <style>#myDiv {position: relative;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var leftvar = Math.random()*1000;
            var topvar = Math.random()*1000;

            var elem = document.getElementById('myDiv');

            elem.style.left = leftvar + 'px';
            elem.style.top  = topvar + 'px';            
        }
        window.onload = myFunction;
    </script>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This looks like it works and is exactly what I'm looking for, but it does not work. The text stays in place.

Comment: Add `position:absolute` to the `div` ;-) `left/right/top/bottom` need a `position` property to work.

Comment: @WilliamOffied - if that code is everything, setting left and top values won't do anything as the element has no position, see above comment!

Answer (score 0):

You've got to try something like this:

```
<body>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var leftvar = Math.random()*1000;
            var topvar = Math.random()*1000;
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');
            myDiv.Left = leftvar;
            myDiv.Top = topvar;
        }
        window.onload = myFunction;
    </script>
    <div id='mydiv'>
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `myDiv.Left = leftvar;   myDiv.Top = topvar;` - invalid. It should be `myDiv.style.left`